# how to tkinter Entry widget .get() compare with int?

Tags: python, get, tkinter, int

I want to accept data from the user in `int` format..but the `.get()` method returns a `str` object.
 using `IntVar` also is not helping. the following is somewhat what i want to do:

```
inp = Entry(master)
#some code here
num = inp.get()

if num >5:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

`Entry.get()` returns a string. use `int` to convert the string into an integer.

```
if int(num) >5: #do something
```

Of course, this may raise an Exception if the string can't be converted to an integer. For example, if the user enters "Hello" instead of a number, or just doesn't write anything at all.

Comment: I guess I should mention that if you call `inp.get()` immediately after creating the Entry, it will always be blank, because the code executes in a millionth of a second, so there's no possible way the user could have typed anything yet.

Comment: the get() works when i click a button..so there's no issue with that..
but the problem comes with the 'if' statement where there is a mis-match